# Google Maps Javascript API Places Library

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Why Google Maps Javascript API Places Library are returning the string "Republica Federativa do Brasil" instead of "Brasil" for the country Brazil in autocomplete function?

It's causing me several problem in my application. Can you help?

Comment: What region and language did you use in Brazil? BR and pt-BR?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a locale issue. You can specify the locale you want to return. See here: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization

```
&region=GB&language=en
```

Replace with the locale codes you need. See [Language codes here](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=p9pdwsai2hDMsLkXsoM05KQ&gid=1)

Comment: @user1633962 That's great. Can you mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks. Click the tick outline to the left of the answer. :)